# create a new id for each clone

Tags: javascript, html, css, clonenode

I am trying to clone a div in a form while also giving each input a unique id. I have reproduced quite a bit of code but it's for a wholistic understanding of what I am trying to create.

Below is my html for the code:

```
  <div class="form-step">
  <div id="readroot">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label for="LegalEntity">Legal Entity</label>
      <input type="radio" name="choice2" id="legalEntity2" value="legalEntity" onclick="filterForm2()" />
      <label for="Individual">Individual</label>
      <input type="radio" name="choice2" id="Individual2" value="Individual" onclick="filterForm2()" />
    </div>
    <div id="lec2" class="legal-entity-content">
      <div class="input-group">
        <label for="CompanyName">Company Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="CompanyName" id="CompanyName" placeholder="Ex. MyPocketCounsel" />
      </div>
      <div class="input-group">
        <label for="RegisteredAddress">Registered Address</label>
        <input type="text" name="RegisteredAddress" id="RegisteredAddress" placeholder="Ex. MyPocketCounsel" />
      </div>
      <div class="input-group">
        <label for="RegistrationNumber">Registration Number</label>
        <input type="text" name="RegistrationNumber" id="RegistrationNumber" placeholder="Ex. MyPocketCounsel" />
      </div>

      <div class="input-group">
        <label for="Definedas">Defined as...</label>
        <input type="text" name="Definedas" id="Definedas" placeholder="Ex. MyPocketCounsel" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="ic2" class="individual-content hide">
      <div class="input-group">
        <label for="First Name">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="First Name" id="First Name" placeholder="Ex. MyPocketCounsel" />
      </div>
      <div class="input-group">
        <label for="Last Name">Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="Last Name" id="Last Name" placeholder="Ex. MyPocketCounsel" />
      </div>
      <div class="input-group">
        <label for="Address">Address</label>
        <input type="text" name="Address" id="Address" placeholder="Ex. MyPocketCounsel" />
      </div>
      <div class="input-group">
        <label for="Defined as">Defined as...</label>
        <input type="text" name="Defined as" id="Defined as" placeholder="Ex. MyPocketCounsel" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="Remove Lender" class="btn btn-remove-lender"
    onclick="if (counter >= 1){
        counter --;
        this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);
    }else{alert('you must have at least one Lender');}">
  </div>
  <span id="writeroot"></span>
    <div class="btns-group">
      <input type="button" id="morefields" value="Add Lender" class="btn btn-add-lender" onclick="moreFields()">

      <a href="#" class="btn btn-prev">Previous</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-next">Next</a>
  </div>
```

Below is my javascript:

```
    const prevBtns = document.querySelectorAll(".btn-prev");
const nextBtns = document.querySelectorAll(".btn-next");
const progress = document.getElementById("progress");
const formSteps = document.querySelectorAll(".form-step");
const progressSteps = document.querySelectorAll(".progress-step");

let formStepsNum = 0;

nextBtns.forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    formStepsNum++;
    updateFormSteps();
    updateProgressbar();
  });
});

prevBtns.forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    formStepsNum--;
    updateFormSteps();
    updateProgressbar();
  });
});

function updateFormSteps() {
  formSteps.forEach((formStep) => {
    formStep.classList.contains("form-step-active") &&
      formStep.classList.remove("form-step-active");
  });

  formSteps[formStepsNum].classList.add("form-step-active");
}

function updateProgressbar() {
  progressSteps.forEach((progressStep, idx) => {
    if (idx < formStepsNum + 1) {
      progressStep.classList.add("progress-step-active");
    } else {
      progressStep.classList.remove("progress-step-active");
    }
  });

  const progressActive = document.querySelectorAll(".progress-step-active");

  progress.style.width =
    ((progressActive.length - 1) / (progressSteps.length - 1)) * 100 + "%";
}

const IndividualContent = document.getElementById("ic");
IndividualContent.classList.add("hide");



function filterForm() {
 
  if(document.getElementById('legalEntity').checked) {
    //hide individual contnet
const IndividualContent = document.getElementById("ic");
IndividualContent.classList.add("hide");
const legalEntityContent = document.getElementById("lec");
legalEntityContent.classList.remove("hide");
console.log('AAA')
  }else  {
    const legalEntityContent = document.getElementById("lec");
    legalEntityContent.classList.add("hide");
    const IndividualContent = document.getElementById("ic");
IndividualContent.classList.remove("hide");

    console.log('BBB')
  }
}
function filterForm2() {
 
  if(document.getElementById('legalEntity2').checked) {
    //hide individual contnet
const IndividualContent = document.getElementById("ic2");
IndividualContent.classList.add("hide");
const legalEntityContent = document.getElementById("lec2");
legalEntityContent.classList.remove("hide");
console.log('YYY');
  }else  {
    const legalEntityContent = document.getElementById("lec2");
    legalEntityContent.classList.add("hide");
    const IndividualContent = document.getElementById("ic2");
IndividualContent.classList.remove("hide");

    console.log('NNN');
  }
  
   if(document.getElementById('legalEntity3').checked) {
    //hide individual contnet
const IndividualContent = document.getElementById("ic2");
IndividualContent.classList.add("hide");
const legalEntityContent = document.getElementById("lec2");
legalEntityContent.classList.remove("hide");
console.log('YYY');
  }else  {
    const legalEntityContent = document.getElementById("lec2");
    legalEntityContent.classList.add("hide");
    const IndividualContent = document.getElementById("ic2");
IndividualContent.classList.remove("hide");

    console.log('NNN');
  }
}

let counter = 0;
function moreFields() {
 
    counter ++;
    let newFields = document.getElementById('readroot').cloneNode(true);
    newFields.id = '';
    newFields.style.display = 'block';
    let newField = newFields.childNodes;
    for (let i=0;i<newField.length;i++) {
        let theName = newField[i].name;
        if (theName)
            newField[i].name = theName + counter;
    }
    let insertHere = document.getElementById('writeroot');
    insertHere.parentNode.insertBefore(newFields,insertHere);
  console.log('is not'+ counter);
  console.log("more fields worked");
}


function showContent() {
  var temp = document.getElementsByTagName("template")[0];
  var clon = temp.content.cloneNode(true);
  document.body.appendChild(clon);
}

function updateSymbol(e){
  var selected = $(".currency-selector option:selected");
  $(".currency-symbol").text(selected.data("symbol"))
  $(".currency-amount").prop("placeholder", selected.data("placeholder"))
  $('.currency-addon-fixed').text(selected.text())
}

$(".currency-selector").on("change", updateSymbol)

updateSymbol()
```

Is there a way to clone the `div` with `id 'readroot'` while changing the id of the two radio inputs to legalEntity3 and Individual3.

Sorry I am new to this any help will be appreciated

Comment: _"while also giving each input a unique id"_ - Why? Just use a common class instead. Numbered ids are a code smell (imho)

Comment: Thanks @Andreas. I use unique IDs because the cloned div will each have two radio inputs to toggle the specific forms as required. With a class it would toggle all the forms with the same class name

Comment: You have two functions in `onclick` event-handlers which aren't in your posted code, you have one element in your JavaScript `getElementById('writeroot')` call, which doesn't appear in your HTML. And which element is supposed to trigger/call the moreFields() function? Can you edit your code down to the "*[mcve]*" code so that we can more accurately reproduce your problem?

Comment: _"With a class it would toggle all the forms with the same class name"_ - Only if you think "globally". Do the actions you need to do relative from the element that triggered the event. Use `.addEventListener()` instead of inline JS and `this` would be one of the radio buttons. Then just traverse the DOM to get the elements you need - relative to the radio buttons. With `readroot` being a class you can get all the related input elements with `this.closest(".readroot").querySelectorAll("input")`. No ids necessary...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of duplicated code here, so as an aside I'd definitely suggest checking out [AlpineJs](https://www.alpinejs.dev/) or [VueJs](https://vuejs.org/) to help you. It's a different way of working but much simpler to achieve the same and more complex interactivity.

To answer your question though. I'd probably go down the route of having the html you want to duplicate inside a `<template>` tag. Here's a simplified example:

#### Html

You can see in the snippet below that I've added some placeholders `{i}` that could easily be whatever you want e.g. `%%placeholder%%` `{replace}` `::replace::`

#### Javascript

Now in the javascript we can clone the template content, add it to a temporary div, replace the placeholders in the divs innerHtml and append the div to the output:

```js
let counter = 0;
let template = document.getElementById('source');
let output = document.getElementById('output');

function moreFields() {
  counter++;

  let div = document.createElement('div');

  div.appendChild(
    template.content.cloneNode(true)
  );

  div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML.replaceAll('{i}', counter);

  output.append(div);
}

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  moreFields();
}
```

```html
<template id="source">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label for="legalEntity{i}">Legal Entity</label>
    <input type="radio" name="choice{i}" id="legalEntity{i}" value="legalEntity{i}" onclick="filterForm({i})" />
    <label for="individual{i}">Individual</label>
    <input type="radio" name="choice{i}" id="individual{i}" value="individual{i}" onclick="filterForm({i})" />
  </div>
</template>

<div id="output">

</div>
```

---

As a comparison here's the same thing implemented using AlpineJs:

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/alpinejs@3.4.1/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>

<div x-data="{
  filter(num) {
    console.log(num)
  }
}">
  <template x-for="i in 10">
    <div :key="i" class="checkbox">
        <label>
          Legal Entity
          <input type="radio" :name="'choice' + i" :value="'legalEntity' + i" @click="filter(i)" />
        </label>
      
        <label>
           Individual
          <input type="radio" :name="'choice' + i" :value="'individual' + i" @click="filter(i)" />
        </label>
      </div>
  </template>
</div>
```